# Converting basic Scheme functions to Haskell equivalents

Tags: regex, haskell, scheme

I am trying to convert scheme code to Haskell code.

For that, I want know how to use scheme's

1. map
2. lambda
3. return port from file path
4. read-line from port
5. append to list
6. regexp-match
7. GUI

in Haskell

could somebody tell me how to do this in haskell?
thanks

Comment: For 1 - 5, all the answers are in R5RS. As for 6 and 7, consult your Scheme implementation's docs.

Comment: thanks for your comment. I think R5RS is about scheme not haskell. Wonder how could it be helpful for me. thanks

Comment: Map and lambda are trivial, just a little different syntax. However you'll have to use a the Haskell's IO monad for ports and it may take some restructuring.

Comment: Without #7, this would be a somewhat reasonable question....

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Essentially you need to learn Haskell, the language, and its library ecosystem. To find libraries and functions, start by learning the [`Prelude`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/4.3.1.0/doc/html/Prelude.html), since many things are defined there. Then move on to Hackage, where you have thousands of libraries to pick from.

Specifically, most of what you need can be found in the Prelude, and [via Hoogle](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/).

1. [`map`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/4.3.1.0/doc/html/Prelude.html#v%3amap) is defined.
2. "lambda" is the syntax: `\x -> ... e ..`.
3. "return port from file path": try [`openFile`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/4.3.1.0/doc/html/System-IO.html#v%3aopenFile)
4. "read-line from port", try [`hGetLine`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/4.3.1.0/doc/html/System-IO.html#v%3ahGetLine)
5. "append to list", try [`++`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/4.3.1.0/doc/html/Prelude.html#v%3a-43--43-)
6. "regexp-match", use one of the [fine regex libraries](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/regex-posix) from Hackage.
7. "GUI", pick one of [gtk2hs](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/gtk) or [wxHaskell](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/wx).

Answer (score 4):

First of all, if you have no experience in Haskell, I would suggest you to read a good introduction like

- [Learn you a Haskell for great good](http://learnyouahaskell.com/)
- [Real World Haskell](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/)

Both are available for free.

Especially, it is important for you, that Haskell has a difference between *pure* (eg. calculations) and *impure* (eg. IO) calculations. Handling them requires you to think differently sometimes. Also, Haskell is lazy and thus your code can possibly not be translated by simple syntax changes.

For the other points, see the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6186998/converting-basic-scheme-fuctions-to-haskell-equivalents/6187187#6187187) of Don Steward.